# Разбить видео на кадры с помощью ffmpeg, сохраняя кадры в файлы с определенными именами по шаблону

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg -i imput.avi %d.png

так я могу разбить видео на кадры, сохраняя эти кадры в файлы. Названия файлов будут соответствовать номеру кадра.
1.png
2.png
3.png
...
А могу ли я называть файлы по формуле номер_кадра*2 ?
Чтобы у меня получилось
2.png - первый кадр
4.png - второй кадр
6.png - третий кадр
...

Comment: есть опция -start_number, позволит стартовать с любой цифры
есть префиксы в виде любого формата даты

Comment: как влепить арифметическое выражение в строку ffmpeg не нашел, приходит на ум только пост переименование

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже пошел по этому пути. Решил на всякий случай спросить. Вдруг я что-то упустил и иду не по оптимальному пути.